# Is 123-reg shared hosting insecure for Joomla/PHP websites?

Tags: php, security, joomla, shared-hosting

My client has a site on 123-reg shared hosting. 123-reg has a non standard implementation setting of display-errors = on in their default php.ini. The default and on other hosts I've used is Off. 123-reg do not let you override this on shared hosting.

The PHP manual states with regard to display-errors "This is a feature to support your development and should never be used on production systems (e.g. systems connected to the internet)." see http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors
I believe this is because file paths etc could get displayed which create an insecure vulnerability.

I have asked 123-reg to either change their default or allow an override. Their response is always the same, upgrade to VPS where it can be overridden. They don't seem to recognise it as a risk for me and other PHP users of their shared hosting. (they even said changing it would stop other shared sites from working!!!)

How much of a risk is this? Should I move the site to a more secure host?

Comment: i applaud a host that has it on, so fix your errors - no errors =no issue

Comment: @Dagon, yes I can fix the errors and have done, but that doesn't necessarily fix the risk. You applaud a host that goes against a clear directive in the PHP manual???

Comment: I had the worst experience with 123-reg.co.uk from all the hosts altogether. Strongly advise to move your client to another host.

Comment: @Dagon you have not idea what the security implications are when stating this. In production servers => display_errors = off; log_errors = on;

Comment: clearly not. i have only been doing this for 10 years. ;)

Comment: My name is James and I work at 123-reg. I would like to thank you for your feedback which I have brought to the attention of the product managers. Whilst we intend to keep display_errors enabled by default to allow customers to debug scripts more easily, we'll shortly introduce a change to the platform allowing users to override this in their local php.ini files. Your feedback is much appreciated Regards James

Comment: Thankyou James, that sounds promising. I hope shortly means days rather than months. My ticket number is 130520-000306. In there you will see a request from me to raise with your technical management. It's a shame the response I got to that request was 'upgrade to VPS'. At least it seems like you are on the ball. Where should I look out for an announcement on being able to override on shared hosting?

Answer (score 1):

While this might be more a question for [server fault](http://serverfault.stackexchange.com) rather than here, I'd like to say that I don't think I'd go with any hosting company that didn't configure PHP for production use.

`display_errors` should be off and then you can turn it on if needed using `ini_set`

However, if your client can't/won't move away from their current hosting try using the following in an include at the top of every file.

```
error_reporting(0); // to disable all errors
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
```

Its not the best solution, but should turn everything off in your code

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion which I will try. Still can't get away from the fact that 123-reg are going against the PHP manual so are insecure for all their shared hosting it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Another solutions other than @fullybaked is setting error_reporting / display_errors from `.htaccess` (if allowed by the host).

Try something like:

`php_flag display_errors off`

`php_value error_reporting {value}`

To get the {value} check the example below:

```
echo E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE; // 2 
echo E_ALL; // 32767
```

Comment: ah I tried php_value display_errors off in .htaccess will try again with php_flag. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can turn off error reporting by using a php.ini file. Simply create the file, place it on your hosting space where you need this turned off and add the following line in it:

display_errors = Off

You can alter most of the php settings like that. As for security, I think that they are as secured as a shared hosting platform can get - I wouldn't really worry about this if I were you.

Comment: unfortunately 123-reg do not let you simply create the file. [quote]123-reg do not let you override this on shared hosting.[quote]